# How to update json data using volley method on Android?

Tags: android

I get the error no value for city.

I'm new to Android. I was unable to pass the spinner data using PHP URL, volley method. And in my XML I'm using the spinner and text views city, id and pass the city list through spinner URL.

Here is my activity:

```
    private void spinnerapi(){
    sprCoun = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    String serverURL = "server url";
    final StringRequest getRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, serverURL,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("officerResponse", response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String str_status = jsonObject.getString("status");
                        String str_message = jsonObject.getString("message");

                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObjectGuest = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            city_name = jsonObjectGuest.getString("cityname");
                            city_id = jsonObjectGuest.getString("cityid");

                            listarraylist.add(new CityModel(city_name));
                        }
                        sprCoun.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
                                (RegistrationActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    // Toast.makeText(context, "" + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("tyghj", String.valueOf(error));
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(getRequest);
}
```

Comment: Please improve your question quality. You can find more tips in: [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pages.

Comment: There are no post parameters

Comment: Any error log? If so please update

Comment: how to make code update data using volley dynamically